# Parse string to valid array

Tags: c#

I need to parse command line arguments to specific datatypes defined by method signature. So, as a input arguments in my `Main` method, I have some of possible cases as follows:

```
[11, 23, 32]
[1,24.254,3]
[ 124 ,2, 3.0125 ]
[1, 25, 03.1], 1 , "a", 42, "aac", ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc"]
```

with all possible combinations of stated cases. There, of course can be errors like unbalanced parentheses, extra `,` or `.`. So, I can successfully validate unbalanced parentheses, but don't know how to parse and validate other stuff. Again, I now that all elements **must** be separated by `,` and know necessary datatype of each element (if my method is `public void MyMethod(string[], int a, string b, double c)` I can parse it accordingly).

Does somebody has any idea of how this can be achieved, already written solution or anything else?

Comment: You're stretching the limits of what should be provided as arguments to a command-line application.  I'd say you need to use an input file formatted in XML or JSON.  Then just pass the path to the file as an arg.

Comment: What are you doing? Creating some kind of script language? Why do you have to parse something in first place? E.g. using CodeDom you can just compile the code (text) without need to parse something.

Comment: @Sinatr Im not OP, but thanks for suggesting CodeDom. I've never heard of it and it looks cool.

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] input = //CLI arguments separated by ,

// "YourType" is the type that holds your method
MethodInfo targetMethod = typeof(YourType).GetMethod("MyMethod");

// YourMethod's parameters
ParameterInfo[] parameters = targetMethod.GetParameters();

// This will contain the converted values
object[] arguments = new object[input.Length];

for(int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
{
    Type paramType = parameters[i].ParameterType;
    if (paramType.IsArray)
    {
        string[] arrayValues = input[i]
                               .Replace("[", String.Empty)
                               .Replace("]", String.Empty)
                               .Split(',');
        arguments[i] = arrayValues
                    .Select(v => Convert.ChangeType(v, paramType.GetElementType())
                    .ToArray();
    }
    else
        arguments[i] = Convert.ChangeType(input[i], paramType);
}
```

You'd then invoke the method with the converted values.

If `MyMethod` is static:

```
targetMethod.Invoke(null, arguments);
```

If `MyMethod` is an instance method

```
YourType instance = // Instantiate a new object
targetMethod.Invoke(instance, arguments);
```

Comment: With class and method: `class Solution {
 public void solution(string[] arr, int iii){
  foreach(string s in arr){
   System.Console.WriteLine("ii " + s);
  }
 }
}
` it outputs nothing. When using just string as method's argument it works. Input is `[a,b,c,d]`. What is going on?

Comment: @Aleksandar The method expects a string array and an int value, yet you say the input is `[a,b,c,d]`. Where is the int value? You need to specify all the method's arguments.